# Refactor algorithm as computation expression?

Tags: algorithm, f#, functional-programming, computation-expression

This question contains spoilers for those who haven't finished [problem 61 of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=61). I wrote an answer to the problem that was imperative so I set out to make a more generic, functional answer. I succeeded but am now trying to figure out how to refactor it as or using computation expressions and am hopelessly confused. The problem is described in detail below but the gist is that you are trying to build up a chain of numbers that, when placed in order, exhibit a property across all adjacent pairs. The candidates for the chain each come from a different pool of numbers meaning that the brute force algorithm has to be clever to avoid needing to search every possible permutation.

My guess at including computation expressions would be to make the search algorithm into a monad somehow, where it continues to add to the solution or dumps the empty list out. But I'm not entirely sure.

```
(*
Triangle, square, pentagonal, hexagonal, heptagonal, and octagonal numbers are
all figurate (polygonal) numbers and are generated by the following formulae:

Triangle        P3,n=n(n+1)/2       1, 3, 6, 10, 15, ...
Square          P4,n=n2             1, 4, 9, 16, 25, ...
Pentagonal      P5,n=n(3n−1)/2      1, 5, 12, 22, 35, ...
Hexagonal       P6,n=n(2n−1)        1, 6, 15, 28, 45, ...
Heptagonal      P7,n=n(5n−3)/2      1, 7, 18, 34, 55, ...
Octagonal       P8,n=n(3n−2)        1, 8, 21, 40, 65, ...

The ordered set of three 4-digit numbers: 8128, 2882, 8281, has three 
interesting properties.

The set is cyclic, in that the last two digits of each number is the first two 
digits of the next number (including the last number with the first).
Each polygonal type: triangle (P3,127=8128), square (P4,91=8281), and pentagonal 
(P5,44=2882), is represented by a different number in the set.
This is the only set of 4-digit numbers with this property.

Find the sum of the only ordered set of six cyclic 4-digit numbers for which 
each polygonal type: triangle, square, pentagonal, hexagonal, heptagonal, and 
octagonal, is represented by a different number in the set.
*)


let rec distribute e = function
    | [] -> [[e]]
    | x::xs' as xs -> (e::xs)::[for xs in distribute e xs' -> x::xs]

// Return a list of all permutations of a list
let rec permute = function
    | [] -> [[]]
    | e::xs -> List.collect (distribute e) (permute xs)

// Return a list rotated until it's minimum element is the head
let canonicalCyclicPermutation (permutationList : 'a list) = 
    let min = Seq.min permutationList
    let rec loop ourList = 
        match ourList with
        | head :: tail when head = min -> ourList
        | head :: tail -> loop (tail @ [head])
    loop permutationList

// Return a list of all permutations of a list that is rotationally/cylically unique
let permutateCycUniq seedList = 
    permute seedList
    |> List.distinctBy canonicalCyclicPermutation

// Generate a sequence of all s-gonal numbers
let polygonalGenerator s = 
    Seq.initInfinite (fun idx -> ((pown (idx+1) 2) * (s-2) - (idx+1)*(s-4))/2)

// Generate a sequence of s-gonal numbers relevant for our exercise
let polygonalCandidates s = 
    s
    |> polygonalGenerator
    |> Seq.skipWhile (fun x -> x <= 999)
    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun x -> x <= 9999)
    |> Seq.cache

// Create the polygonal numbers as a list not seq
let polygonalCandidatesL s = 
    polygonalCandidates s
    |> Seq.toList

// Returns true if the last digits of first input are first digits in last input
let sharesDigits xxvv vvyy = 
    (xxvv / 100) = (vvyy % 100)

// Returns true if a sequence is cyclical
let isCyclical intSeq = 
    (Seq.append intSeq (Seq.take 1 intSeq))
    |> Seq.pairwise 
    |> Seq.fold (fun acc (num1,num2) -> acc && (sharesDigits num1 num2)) true

// Returns an empty list if the candidate number does not share digits
// with the list head, otherwise returns the list with the candidate at the head
let addCandidateToSolution (solution : int list) (number : int) =
    match solution with
    | (head::tail) when sharesDigits number head -> number::head::tail
    | _ -> []

// Returns a sequence of all valid solutions generated by trying to add
// a sequence of candidates to all solutions in a sequence
let addCandidatesToSolution (solutions : int list seq) (candidates : int seq) =
    Seq.collect (fun solution -> 
                 Seq.map (fun candidate -> 
                          addCandidateToSolution solution candidate)
                          candidates
                |> Seq.filter (not << List.isEmpty)) 
              solutions

// Given a list of side lengths, we return a sequence of cyclical solutions
// from the polygonal number families in the order they appear in the list
let generateSolutionsFromPolygonalFamilies (seedList : int list) = 
    let solutionSeeds = 
        seedList 
        |> List.head
        |> polygonalCandidates
        |> Seq.map (fun x -> [x])

    let solutions = 
        Seq.fold (fun acc elem -> (addCandidatesToSolution acc elem)) 
                 solutionSeeds 
                 ((List.tail seedList) |> List.map polygonalCandidatesL)
        |> Seq.filter isCyclical
    solutions

// Find all cyclical sequences from a list of polygonal number families
let FindSolutionsFromFamilies intList = 
    intList
    |> permutateCycUniq
    |> Seq.collect generateSolutionsFromPolygonalFamilies
    |> Seq.toList

// Given in the problem
let sampleAnswer = FindSolutionsFromFamilies [3;4;5]

// The set of answers that answers the problem
#time
let problemAnswer = FindSolutionsFromFamilies [3 .. 8]
#time // 0.09s wow!
```

Comment: What do you want to gain by doing that? Value of computation expressions is in capturing a common pattern in a computation and abstracting it away. What is the common pattern you wish to abstract away here?

Comment: Apart from the applicability of custom computation expressions, you could certainly rewrite parts of your program into sequence expressions or even query expressions. But that wouldn't necessarily help with readability or efficiency, while a different choice of data structure, e.g. a set of dictionaries to determine the cyclic chains, may allow you to shave off another couple of milliseconds.

Comment: Mostly I'm trying to understand how to use computation expressions. I don't get them and am looking for practice. The common pattern I'm thinking could be abstracted would be the search part of the algorithm where it continues down the chain of possible solutions until it either resolves to nothing or finds a solution.

Answer (score 1):

While being sceptical at first, I have to admit that the thinking behind this question is pretty sound, while an actual implementation appears quite elusive.  Owing to the necessity of providing the equivalent monadic signature of `member Bind : ma:'a list * f:('a -> 'b list) -> 'b list` for a given datastructure, it's only natural to stick to F# list and use its corresponding higher order function, `List.collect`.

```
type ListBuilder () =
    member __.Return x = [x]
    member __.Bind(ma, f) = List.collect f ma

let myList a b = ListBuilder () {
    let! x = a
    let! y = b
    return x, y } 

myList [1..2] [3..4]    // [(1, 3); (1, 4); (2, 3); (2, 4)]
```

This minimum but slick cartesian product doesn't get us very far. We need to make the execution down the chain conditional, requiring an additional member, `Zero`. Obviously, the fixed arity is a major drawback of this approach.

```
type MyListBuilder () =
    member __.Zero _ = []
    member __.Return x = [x]
    member __.Bind(ma, f) = List.collect f ma

let myListXY cmp a b c = MyListBuilder () {
    let! r = a
    let! s = b
    if cmp r s then 
        let! t = c
        if cmp s t then 
            if cmp t r then 
                return r, s, t } 

let T n k = if n < 2 then 0 else ((n - 2) * k * k - (n - 4) * k) / 2

let figurate s min max =
    Seq.initInfinite ((+) 1)
    |> Seq.map (T s)
    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun n -> n < max)
    |> Seq.filter (fun n -> n >= min)
    |> Seq.toList

myListXY (fun x y -> x % 100 = y / 100)
    (figurate 3 1000 10000)
    (figurate 5 1000 10000)
    (figurate 4 1000 10000) // [(8128, 2882, 8281)]
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. The "fixed arity" as you say was what I was hoping could be extracted away. My hunch says that the `bind`ing function needs to be some sort of `reduce` or `fold` over the list/sequence of groups to search through. I'm not having any luck writing that, though.